# Correction for XML script that I've written

Tags: xml, xsd, schema, dtd

I have only theoretical and basic knowledge of XML and have been trying to understand the concept of internal and external DTD, schemas better. I got myself a question and wrote an XML script for it. I have no idea how to run it and also don't even know if what I have written is right. Would love to hear corrections and suggestions for the question and answer given below. Also, it'd be of great help if somebody can tell me how to run it, as I want more practical knowledge too.
**`Question: Create an XML schema for a catalog of cars, where each car has the following child elements: company_name, model, year, color, and engine type.`**

```
The answer I've written:
<?xml version ="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!==cars.xsd
    A simple schema for cars.xml
-->
<xsd:schema
xmlns:xsd="http:///www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
targetNamespace="https://cs.uccs.edu/carCatalog"
xmlns="https://cs.uccs.edu/carCatalog">
<xsd:element name="Cars">
<xsd:complexType>
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd: element name= "company" type="xs.string"/>
<xsd: element name= "model" type="xs.string"/>
<xsd: element name= "year" type="xs.string"/>
<xsd: element name= "color" type="xs.string"/>
<xsd: element name= "engine" type="xs.string"/>
</xsd:sequence>
<xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>


<!--carcatalog.xml-->
<cars
xmlns="https://cs.uccs.edu/carCatalog"
xmlns:xsi="http:///www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemalocation="https://cs.uccs.edu/carCatalog/cae.xsd"
<company> Volks Wagon</company>
<model> abcxyz</model>
<year> 2018</year>
<color> Blue</color>
<engine> 4 cylinders</engine>
</cars>
```

Everything I've written is with the help of examples from my textbook (which is where I got the question too). Please try and describe in simple but detailed manner what's wrong(if any) with the above script. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going to give you the corrected answer but will provide enough tips so you are able to do it yourself.

first, best way to see if your xml or xsd is syntactical correct is to use a validator. these can be used online or offline. Notepad++ has an extension called xml that will help you or you can go to: https://freeformatter.com/xml-validator-xsd.html

If you use the validator on the xml schema (xsd) you will see that it will not pass.

- comments are between
- the url of the xsd namespace is invalid it has a / too many.
- every type that you open needs to be closed
- there are no spaces between de namespace prefix and the type definition.
- all namespace prefixed must be defined
- between a namespace prefix and the type there is a : not a .
- By adding the elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" to the schema with the correct setting you can specify how the target namespace is used.

If you fix these things the xml schema will be valid and usable, but i assume you want more than one car in your list of Cars. this can be achieved by setting the min and max occurs on the element Cars.

the xml needs some attention as wel.

- Xml is case sensitive so cars and Cars are different elements.
- al xml elements haven an open < and close >
- your schema location must point exactly where you've placed the file locally and the name of the file must me correct.

Hope this helps you in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm going to try the Notepad++ validator and see if I can understand/correct my code better. The bullets were really helpful :)